# Which programming languages have no-indexed lists?

Tags: list, data-structures, programming-languages

As far as I'm a Java developer, I used to understand Lists as indexed data structures (it's Collections basics, actually), but naturally Lists aren't indexed. So far, which commonly used programming languages have no-indexed Lists?

Answer (score 1):

A list is an ordered collection. So by definition its elements are indexed by integers. If you have a collection that is not ordered then it is not a list.

Comment: well, I see at list one more person who thinks that Lists are indexed by nature. List is a data structure which: 1) preservs order of elements and 2) is able to keep similar elements. that's all, indexed Lists - just a kind of Lists

Comment: I don't understand the statement "indexed Lists - just a kind of Lists". All lists are indexed by definition with integers. If they were not then they would not be ordered, and by definition would then not be a list.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a list that is not indexed by integers?

Comment: If you don't have order (indexed by integers) then what you have is a Set or perhaps a MultiSet if you want to allow duplicates.